# Add npm package to filament and import it

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, npm, laravel-filament

I am quite new to Filament PHP, Livewire and Alpine.js. I have already searched on Google and Stackoverflow but couldn't find an answer.

I want to create my own custom form field with QuillJs. I have already run the command `php artisan make:form-field QuillEditor` which has generated me the `QuillEditor.php` class and my `quill-editor.blade.php` blade file.

However, at the moment I am using a CDN to include my `.js` and `.css` files. I want to get rid of that and import Quill via my npm modules. I have no no `app.js` so far in my resources folder where I can import my QuillJs module.

Please tell me what I have to do in order to import Quill in my `quill-editor.blade.php` and also how I can import and make Quill register modules such as [quill-image-uploader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/quill-image-uploader)?

This is my code so far I want to change:

```
<script src="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet">

<x-dynamic-component
    :component="$getFieldWrapperView()"
    :field="$field"
>
    <div
        x-data="{ state: $wire.$entangle('{{ $getStatePath() }}') }"
        x-init="
            const quill = new Quill($refs.editor, {
                theme: 'snow'
            });

            quill.setText(state);

            quill.on('text-change', () => {
                console.log('get html', quill.root.innerHTML);
                state = quill.root.innerHTML;
            });
    "
    >
        <div
            wire:ignore
            x-ref="editor"
        ></div>
    </div>
</x-dynamic-component>
```

Kind regards

Comment: https://filamentphp.com/docs/3.x/support/assets#registering-javascript-files this part of the documentation explains how to do it, there's also a part purely for alpine. And for an example you can also use this repo created by Dan Harrin himself: https://github.com/laracasts/laracasts-building-advanced-components-for-filament/tree/main

Comment: I have read and seen this. But it does not handle npm modules... Just plain `.js` and `.css` files

Comment: It does but it uses esbuild to compile it to a single file. Also you can always just do it in the default Laravel way as long as you don't make it a plugin: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55539701/import-quill-js-into-laravel-using-mix-webpack